# Domain marked as spam after thousands of stolen emails subscribed to newletter

Tags: email, gmail, spam

Gmail recently started marking all emails from my domain as spam because 'Emails sent by noreply@mydomain.com are often spam'.
I searched around for a bit and noticed that suddenly thousands of new email adresses had subscribed to our newsletter, presumably by a spambot, and a large enough group of people has marked the confirmation email as spam for gmail to mark all of my emails as spam.

I was already using a hidden 'name' field to filter out earlier spambots, but they suddenly started going around that.
How do other sites with a newsletter subscription box in their footer prevent spambots from subscribing with thousands of emails, most I see don't even use a honeypot or captcha? Is there a way to fix my domain's reputation?

Comment: Which email address do you use as "envelope sender"? (`RCPT TO` in SMTP session)

Comment: They are sent via amazon SES so they generate a randomstring@bounce.mydomain.com address

Comment: I would suggest making them `fixedstring+randomstring@bounce.mydomain.com`.  As you describe it may look too much like checking recipients' address by a spammer.